# Why these strings are not equals?

Tags: java

I have a string:

```java
String DRUM_R = "Bang Bang";
```

I also have a string, that I want to repeat twice:

```java
String sound = "Bang";
```

I create a new line:

```java
String s = (sound + " ").repeat(2);
```

Why, when I compare these strings, do I get false?

```java
System.out.println(s.equals(DRUM_R));
```

Result: false.

These strings are exactly the same. Why does this happen?

Comment: Hint: Print the lengths of the two strings which will give you a clue `System.out.println(DRUM_R.length()); System.out.println(s.length());`

Comment: String s is `"Bang Bang "`, not `"Bang Bang"`..., maybe you should use `String.join(" ", sound, sound)` instead, or just `sound + " " + sound`.

Comment: To debug, compare the code points of each character in each string: `DRUM_R.codePoints().toArray()` and `s.codePoints().toArray()`. You’ll find an extra `32` on the end of one, representing a SPACE character.

Answer (score 1):

"Bang Bang" is not the same as "Bang Bang "

these are some examples of how you can do it

```
String DRUM_R = "Bang Bang";
String sound = "Bang";
System.out.println(sound); //"Bang"

String s = (sound + " ").repeat(2);
System.out.println(s); //"Bang Bang "

System.out.println(s.equals(DRUM_R)); //false "Bang Bang " != "Bang Bang"

s = s.substring(0, s.length()-1);
System.out.println(s); //"Bang Bang"

s = String.join(" ", sound, sound);
System.out.println(s); //"Bang Bang"

s = sound + " "+ sound;
System.out.println(s); //"Bang Bang"
```

you can also make a function like this one that will do what you want

```
public String repeatWord(String word, int n) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        sb.append(word);
        if (i != n - 1) {
            sb.append(" ");
        }
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

this is an example of usage

```
String repeatedWord = repeatWord("Bang", 5);
System.out.println(repeatedWord); // "Bang Bang Bang Bang Bang"
```